# How to extend CAS on JAVA Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cas, jasig

I just want to know how to extend CAS on Java `SpringBoot` using pom.xml.

Here are the things I want to do.

Whenever I click the Forgot password link in CAS login page, it would redirect it to my custom forgot password site. Same goes to change the password.

Create Password management base on my existing policy.

Having user locked out after unsuccessful attempts.

I want to use Java spring-boot with maven.

An example project will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cas-sso

Comment: I saw this one. This is the guide to setup the cas server + springboot client. What i need is to create change password using cas overlay template. I have no idea on this. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you described above is provided by CAS 5 automatically and you just need to configure your deployment accordingly, not extend. See the CAS documentation for more info.

https://apereo.github.io/cas/

There is functionality that allows you to change the password, implement password policies and lock/throttle accounts.

CAS 5 is based on Spring Boot.